# Where is the Template Route Manager

Tags: template-routes

I am taking over a project built with EE. I am completely new to EE, I was trying to figure out how the routing works and I came across documentation about the Template Route Manager. When I login to the admin however I do not see the Route Manager anywhere.

[image: Screenshot - No Route Manager]

Any idea why this may be?

How do I access the routes for pages that exist?

Answer (score 0):

Odd - I'd guess that the view files weren't properly replaced when the install went from the previous version to 2.8.1. If you upgrade to the current 2.0 version (2.11.2) that should fix it.

In the meantime, access Template Routes via **admin.php?/cp/design/url_manager**.

Comment: Is it possible, that since this is before template routes parse order could be changed, it's only accessibly via the **Access** section of a particular template?

Comment: Could be! Don't have a local copy of 2.8 to check on.

Comment: When I go to admin.php/cp/design/url_manager I get redirected to cp/design/manager. After a lot of digging around I came across the Structure plugin. I'm not sure if having this disables the Route Manager but It looks like the routes are controlled inside Structure